# Unresolved <ejb-link>

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I'm developing in NetBeans 7, with EJB3.1 and Glassfish 3.1.
I am trying to reference the Local Interface of a Session Bean in a JAR from a POJO in a WAR.
When I deploy to Glassfish I receive:

```
SEVERE: Unresolved <ejb-link>: TaskTool-ejb#ContextFacade
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [com.oracle.eas_TaskTool-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT]
SEVERE: Error: Unresolved <ejb-link>: TaskTool-ejb#ContextFacade
```

I used the NetBeans helper to generate the code to reference the Session Bean's Local Interface and it generated the `<ejb-local-ref>` section in web.xml for me.

```
@Local
public interface ContextFacadeLocal {
    void create(Context context);
    void edit(Context context);
    void remove(Context context);
    Context find(Object id);
    List<Context> findAll();
    List<Context> findRange(int[] range);
    int count();
    List<Context> findRootContexts();
}

@Stateless
public class ContextFacade extends AbstractFacade<Context> implements ContextFacadeLocal {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TaskToolPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ContextFacade() {
        super(Context.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Context> findRootContexts() {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Context> query = builder.createQuery(Context.class);
        Root<Context> c = query.from(Context.class);
        query.select(c).where(builder.isNull(c.get("parent")));
        query.orderBy(builder.asc(c.get("id")));

        TypedQuery<Context> q = em.createQuery(query);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
}

@FacesConverter(value = "contextConverter")
public class contextConverter implements Converter {

    ContextFacadeLocal contextFacade = lookupContextFacadeLocal();

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string) {
        return contextFacade.find(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {ntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ContextFacade() {
        super(Context.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Context> findRootContexts() {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Context> query = builder.createQuery(Context.class);
        Root<Context> c = query.from(Context.class);
        query.select(c).where(builder.isNull(c.get("parent")));
        query.orderBy(builder.asc(c.get("id")));

        TypedQuery<Context> q = em.createQuery(query);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
}

@FacesConverter(value = "contextConverter")
public class contextConverter implements Converter {

    ContextFacadeLocal contextFacade = lookupContextFacadeLocal();

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string) {
        return contextFacade.find(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
        return ((Context) o).getId().toString();
    }

    private ContextFacadeLocal lookupContextFacadeLocal() {
        try {
            javax.naming.Context c = new InitialContext();
            //return (ContextFacadeLocal) c.lookup("java:global/com.oracle.eas_TaskTool-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.oracle.eas_TaskTool-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/ContextFacade!com.oracle.eas.ejbs.ContextFacadeLocal");
            return (ContextFacadeLocal) c.lookup("java:comp/env/TaskTool-ejb#ContextFacade");

        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
            throw new RuntimeException(ne);
        }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>ContextFacade</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local>com.oracle.eas.ejbs.ContextFacadeLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>TaskTool-ejb#ContextFacade</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
</web-app>
```

**UPDATE**

For clarity:

I don't have an ejb-jar.xml at all.

Using either `<ejb-link>TaskTool-ejb/ContextFacade</ejb-link>` or `<ejb-link>com.oracle.eas_TaskTool-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/ContextFacade</ejb-link>` works.

Please see bkail answers below for explanation.  Many thanks!

Comment: I found that removing the section from web.xml and using the global name below worked.  Can anybody tell me why the section in web.xml caused an error?  Did NetBeans generate incorrect code?    java:global/com.oracle.eas_TaskTool-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/ContextFacade!com.oracle.eas.ejbs.ContextFacadeLocal

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue when trying to deploy my application, NetBeans generated this code in my web.xml on its own.

Check your web.xml and see if you see this:

```
<ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>appName</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <ejb-link>AppName#SomeClass</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
```

if so just remove it comepletely, it should deploy after.

Comment: Worked for me, I don't know what triggers netbeans to do this, it was the first time it happened when developing webservices...

Answer (score 2):

What is the name of your EJB module?  Unless the jar file is named literally "TaskTool-ejb.jar", then you need to use either:

```
<ejb-link>TaskTool-ejb.jar#ContextFacade</ejb-link>
```

or:

```
<ejb-link>TaskTool-ejb/ContextFacade</ejb-link>
```

The latter assumes you haven't overridden the module-name in ejb-jar.xml.

Update: Based on your own comment, perhaps you need to use "com.oracle.eas_TaskTool-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#ContextFacade" or "com.oracle.eas_TaskTool-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/ContextFacade".

Comment: bkail, I don't have an ejb-jar.xml at all.  Using either <ejb-link>TaskTool-ejb/ContextFacade</ejb-link> or <ejb-link>com.oracle.eas_TaskTool-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/ContextFacade</ejb-link> works.  Could you explain the difference between using # or / and why I need this section in web.xml at all?

Comment: The # syntax is <uri>#<ejb-name>, where uri is the physical JAR name in the EAR, and ejb-name is the bean name (default is the short class name of the annotated EJB).  The / syntax is <module-name>/<ejb-name>, where the module-name is specified in ejb-jar.xml (default is the URI without the extension).  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "why I need this section in web.xml at all"?  Do you mean the whole ejb-local-ref or the ejb-link?

Comment: I mean the ejb-local-ref.  Glassfish 3.1 doesn't seem to need it.

Comment: The ejb-local-ref is declaring a reference to allow lookup("java:comp/env/ContextFacade").  If nothing in your code is using that (or you have an @EJB(name="ContextFacade") elsewhere), then you don't need the ejb-local-ref.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. Snippet from Glassfish Log:

```
SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [.....] : Error: Unresolved <ejb-link>: #NotifyMe
```

When you use annotations in Web service (which are strongly recommended) remove all rows from sun-web.xml which are touching web service.

I.e. in my sun-web.xml has only basic informations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

As you can see, there is nothing specific about application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TomEE don't use EAR > EJB / WAR classloader, and them are treated in single-war, 'MyEjbJar#MyEJB' cannot be used as an ejb-link target, we must change

```
    <ejb-link>MyEjb.jar#MyEJB</ejb-link>
```

in /WEB-INF/web.xml to

```
    <ejb-link>MyEJB</ejb-link>
```

instead.